# 'System.ArgumentException' when trying to use SetPixel (x, y, Color)

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing, grayscale, argumentexception

I am trying to create a white picture (greyscale format).

So here is the code I use:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1,        
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, i.Width, i.Height);
```

"I" is an existing Bitmap image. I am playing with its channels.
The principle is to create a 1 pixel image in greyscale, give this pixel the white color and then enlarge it to the good size.

But I have this as a result:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Drawing.dll"

I tried `Color.White` but it isn't allowed for greyscale or indexed formats.

What are my other options to fix this?

Comment: Not all enumerated pixel formats are actually supported.. The rest of the code is just weird - why not clear with the color you want it to have???

Comment: The PixelFormat enum has pixel formats that are not actually implemented fully.  Like 16bppGrayScale.  Way back when, GDI+ was designed with the assumption that some pixel formats would become available as display technology improved.  That did not happen, LCD monitors were actually quite a step back from CRTs and are not yet close to catching up.  Monitors that support 16bpp grayscale do exist, you'll find them in the radiology department of your local hospital.  You know what they cost when you get the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to do it without converting to greyscale?

```
Bitmap A = new Bitmap(i.Width, i.Height);
for (int x = 0; x < i.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < i.Height; y++)
    {
        Color C = i.GetPixel(x, y);
        Color WD = Color.FromArgb(C.R, 255, C.G, 0);
        A.SetPixel(x, y, WD);
    }
```

Simply done by placing colour channels in the desired order

Comment: I'm personally debugging your code, seems there's something missing.

Comment: Did you give a value to the i variable ? It's a Bitmap I opened from a .bmp file.

Otherwise your answer, I already viewed it. That's what gave me the idea to use color.FromArgb.

Comment: I'm loading `i` with an image, yes.
There seems to be an enum named PaletteFlag, which from the members it seems to define how the colours are used, anyway I couldn't find a property in the bitmap class to set these flags.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry I have messed up a little with the edits. Can't I remove myself unuseful edits ?

Yes I just saw the Palette flag. But which use can be done with it ?

Comment: : You can re-edit your post or just delete it.
I shall now tell you that we should completely change the question, `bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);` is also throwing the same exception.

Comment: So what, according to you, would be the question ?

Comment: I changed the algorithm for you into one equivalent. It does the thing you want, but if want the channels individually in grayscale, it'll need another algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll look over that, test and send feedback !

Comment: You definitely rock ! Indeed it seems perfect ! Seems I need more practice.

The remaining question is : Will have I to convert ARGB to RGBA ?
I don't know if it's trivial.

Comment: Thanks. And no, you just have to do it as it's meant to, FromArgb takes ARGB values and FromRgba (if any) takes RGBA values.
Also I suggest to merge your question and your own answer to clarify the question.

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll post all the code. It's currently ugly I know but it's for a quick need.
I am converting normal maps from the usual purple format to the orange format. It's just channels swapping.

[image: Converting normal map from purple format to orange format]

I am using the AForge framework to do this more easily. I extract needed channels (only the red to swap) from the input pictures. I clone it, that adds an alpha channel too to the RGB entry. Then I modify the channels of the copy to get the new image.

The problem is for the red and blue channels that need new pitch white and pitch black images.

I need to create an image either in "Format8bppIndexed" (which would be nice) or at worse in "Format16bppGrayScale". SetPixel doesn't accept indexed format.

```
//Opening the normal map (RGB)

Bitmap i = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile("C:/Users/KuroTenshi/WD/normalblue/07_bloom_doublemetaldoor_d_high_n.bmp");

//Extract the red channel, that will be put in an alpha channel

ExtractChannel filterR = new ExtractChannel(RGB.R);
Bitmap r = filterR.Apply(i);

//Clone the input image to have a base for the output (it's converted to ARGB)

Bitmap j = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(i);

//Extract channels to modify

ExtractChannel filterR2 = new ExtractChannel(RGB.R);
ExtractChannel filterB2 = new ExtractChannel(RGB.B);
ExtractChannel filterA2 = new ExtractChannel(RGB.A);
Bitmap r2 = filterR2.Apply(j);
Bitmap b2 = filterB2.Apply(j);
Bitmap a2 = filterA2.Apply(j);

//Putting input's red channel into output's alpha channel

a2 = r;

//Creating a white Bitmap for the output's red channel

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, i.Width, i.Height);

r2 = bmp;

//Creating a black Bitmap for the output's blue channel

Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
bmp2.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(0,0,0));
bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp2, i.Width, i.Height);

b2 = bmp2;

//Replace channels

ReplaceChannel replaceFilter = new ReplaceChannel(RGB.A, a2);
replaceFilter.ApplyInPlace(j);
replaceFilter = new ReplaceChannel(RGB.R, r2);
replaceFilter.ApplyInPlace(j);
replaceFilter = new ReplaceChannel(RGB.B, b2);
replaceFilter.ApplyInPlace(j);

//Save output


j.Save("C:/Users/KuroTenshi/WD/normalblue/07_bloom_doublemetaldoor_d_high_n2.bmp");
```